# How to add new model into ASP.NET core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Inside Visual Studio 2019, I create a project with ASP.NET Core MVC Web App:

[The structure of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx6qj.png)

Create new Controller/View follow this step:

*In Solution Explorer, right-click the Controllers folder > Add > New Scaffolded Item*: [Add New Scaffolded Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH0Wd.png).

After pressing "Add" the  [Add New Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdZc8.png) appears. I can not find where Controller, View or Model structure located to "Add" anymore. So:

**1. How can I add new Controller/View/Model?**

**2. Is my Visual Studio 2019 missing installed structure?**

Comment: If possible, you can try to repair or reinstall your Visual Studio, then check if it can help fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did do it yesterday and it works absolutely well!